# Calling a class from same package and assigning variables

Tags: java, class, arraylist, random, import

I'm trying to pull the RestaurantSelector1 class into CuisineChoice so that I can be able to have users input choices that I can then assign to the variables in RestaurantSelector1(if that makes sense. This is what I have:

In RestaurantSelector1:

```
public class RestaurantSelector1 {

public static String getRandom(List<String[]> list) {
Random random = new Random();
int listAccess = random.nextInt(list.size());
String[] s = list.get(listAccess);
return s[random.nextInt(s.length)];


}


public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<String[]> WestVillageCuisine = new ArrayList<String[]>();
WestVillageCuisine.add(Expensive.WestVillage.italian);
.
.
.
WestVillageCuisine.add(Expensive.WestVillage.greek);

final String[] randomCuisine =      WestVillageCuisine.get(random.nextInt(WestVillageCuisine.size()));
final String randomRestaurant =  randomCuisine[random.nextInt(randomCuisine.length)];
final String[] randomWVItalian = WestVillageCuisine.get(0);
final String westVillageItalian = r    randomWVItalian[random.nextInt(randomWVItalian.length)];
System.out.println(getRandom(WestVillageCuisine));
System.out.println(randomRestaurant);
System.out.println(westVillageItalian);
}
```

And this is Cuisine Choice class:

```
class CuisineChoice{
public static void main(String[] args){
RestaurantSelector1 A = new RestaurantSelector1();

System.out.println("What price range are you looking for? one = $-$$ and two = $$$-$$$$");
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String price = scan2.next();
    if (price.equals("two")){
        price = "Expensive";
    System.out.println("In which neighborhood would you like to eat?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String location = scan.next();
if (null != location)switch (location) {
        case "Tribeca":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location + " " + type + " " + price);


            break;

            }
        case "West Village":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location + " " + type + " " + price);

                break;
            }
        case "Flatiron":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        case "Chelsea":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    }  
    else{
    price= "Inexpensive"; System.out.println("In which neighborhood would you like to eat?");
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
   String location1 = scan3.next();
if (null != location1)switch (location1) {
        case "Tribeca":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location1 + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location1 + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        case "West Village":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location1 + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location1 + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        case "Flatiron":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location1 + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location1 + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        case "Chelsea":{
            System.out.println("Great! And what type cuisine would you like in " + location1 + " ?");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String type = scan1.next();
            System.out.print(location1 + " " + type + " " + price);
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }

}
}
}
```

I just can't figure out how to use the user inputs of location and cuisine types as inputs to get a random restaurant of that cuisine in that location.  I'm having trouble even getting the RestaurantSelector1 class to show up in CuisineChoice at all.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would strongly recommend to pass [Java tutorial](https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivhJShydfVAhXHBZoKHTdfDVwQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1m2PqVsncDnYixu6Kv67G70IpBw) . It perfectly describes all the basics which you're having troubles with now

Answer (score 0):

Both have main method, which one is the start point of the application, and what is the structure of your application, are they in the same package or different package? and you have some typo in code like if statement, it doesn't have "{" to open the statement, and in the case statement you don't need "{}".

```
if (null != location)switch (location) {
```

It should be:

```
if (null != location){ switch (location) {
```

Comment: I would want the start point to be where you are asking for user input. The switch and case statements were suggested to me on netbeans, I will fix them now.

Comment: I mean each class has main method, and the application needs only one main method to start, or at least specify on of them as start point for the application. Set in this main method (the start of the application) the code to ask for the user input.